# Constructors taking rvalue reference in C++ standard library

Tags: c++, c++11, std

While I think certain classes in the C++ standard library should have a constructor overload that takes in a non-const rvalue reference, they do not actually. Examples include the family of `stringstream` classes and the standard exception classes. Why they don't have a constructor that takes in `std::string&&`? These classes should be able to move the `string` argument to their internal storage. Where am I wrong? Do I just have a false assumption about the underlying implementation of the classes?

I guess the exception classes do should provide a constructor overload that takes in `std::string&&`, for allocating a new `std::string` for internal storage by the exception classes may well cause another exception to be thrown.

Comment: `stringstream` does have move constructor, see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/stringstream/

Comment: @XiaotianPei What I take to mean is why it doesn't have one that takes `std::string&&`?

Comment: what's the point of it?

Comment: @Xiaotian: the same as any other move constructor

Comment: the one with `const string&` is meant to provide content as opposed to providing storage.

Answer (score 1):

I'm speculating, but I imagine it was not included because it would not be useful for typical implementations. There is no advantage to keeping the contents of the stream in a contiguous array and advantages to being arranged more like a singly linked list of buffers so that no copying has to be done while writing to the stream, so I imagine the expected implementations would not be able to take advantage of the constructor.

Comment: Then what about the exception classes? I guess they do should provide a constructor overload that takes in `std::string&&`, for allocating a new `std::string` for internal storage by the exception classes may just cause another exception to be thrown.

Comment: All three major implementations use a contiguous array. Only two of them uses a `basic_string` for storage internally, however.

Comment: @T.C.: Just curious.  For the implementations that use a `std::string` for internal storage, how do they implement the `noexcept` copy members for the exception types?  Or perhaps `terminate()` is an acceptable response?

Comment: @HowardHinnant I was talking about `stringstream`/`stringbuf`, not exceptions

Answer (score 1):

`stringstream` uses `stringbuf` as its internal storage. `stringbuf` doesn't take `string&&` as its argument. But you may ask why `stringbuf` doesn't do this....